# Make program that plays a different song on loop every hour [Python]

Tags: python, clock

I am trying to make a program that will play a certain song on loop each hour of the day. For example from 12pm-1pm a certain song will continuously play and then once it turns 1pm a different song will continuously play until 2pm.

I'm fairly new to Python so I don't really know where to start. I've tried doing research but I can't find much. To give you an idea of how stuck I am I can't even get a song to play normally.

If someone could give me a little snip of code to get started with that would be greatly appreciated. I would like for my program to reference the system clock to find the time of day, but I'm not sure how complex that would be.

Sorry if I sound like I'm just trying to get someone to just do stuff for me but I just really can't figure out where to start and I'm desperate for any kind of help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
#Open your favorite song on youtube, after every 2 hours and have a break from your work.

import webbrowser
import time
import datetime

total_breaks = 3
break_count = 0

print("The program has started on : "+time.ctime())
while(break_count<total_breaks):
    time.sleep(7200) #interval is of 2 hrs = 7200 seconds
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtOvBOTyX00')
    break_count = break_count + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vlc.py file to play songs. Get the file from http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree;f=generated;b=HEAD. Save it as vlc.py

You haven't specified where from you wish to play songs. Let's assume you have a folder having collection of mp3. We will play each song in that folder for an hour.

Following code should play each song approx 1 hour.

```
from vlc import *
import time,os


#get a list of all songs in the current directory
songs =  [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('mp3')]


#loop over all the songs present in current directory
for song in songs:

    #to play a song using vlc
    p = MediaPlayer(song)   
    p.play()

    #a delay so that attributes of object p can be initialized 
    time.sleep(1)

    #playing song continously for 1 hour from current time.
    starttime = int(time.time())

    while True:
        now = int(time.time())

        #p.is_playing() sets to 1 if the song is being played.
        # Keep looping till song is being played
        if p.is_playing() == 1:
            pass

        #if song stops check if 1 hour is over or not.
        #If not then play again.
        elif (now - starttime) < 3599:
            p.release()
            p = MediaPlayer(song)
            p.play()
            time.sleep(1)

        #if an hour is gone then move on to the next song.
        else:

            p.release()
            break;

    # print "time over"
    # print time.time()
```

Make sure you keep vlc.py, all mp3 songs and the file for the above code in the same directory.